# Error importing project set (.psf file)

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am using Eclipse indigo SR1 and installed subclipse 1.8.22 plugin.

I have a .psf file (Project Set File).
When I try to import project set (Right Click on psf file and select 'Import Project Set') I am getting below error :

```
An error occurred importing this project set.
Projects for repository type org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature could not be loaded as the type could not be found.
```

One more thing, when i try to see what is already installed, it shows SVNKit and subversion 
also

[image]

I am not sure if these plaugins are required for subclipse or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This - org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature is an ID for the Subversive plugin, not Subclipse.  So it sounds like the PSF was made using the Subversive plugin and you are trying to import it using the Subclipse plugin.

Comment: thanks mark, i uninstalled the subclipse plugin and installed the subversive......and its working :)